# Problem after assigining port number to MSSQL2005 named instance:Service won't start

Tags: java, sql-server, windows-xp, service, ireport

I'll like to combine both my initial problem which leads me to this one and this one.

1. my first problem was to be able to connect jaspersoft ireport 3.7.0 to MSSQL2005.I downloaded the jar from microsoft downloads and added the `jdbc4.jar` from the `irepot>tool>classpath>add jar`.    
   It went fine but i needed the port number other than 1433 since i'm using a named instance.so my first question is on which port to connect to a MSSQL2005 named instance?
2. During my search on google i found lot's of article like [this one][1] and [link text][2].

   - i first did: `start>Microsoft SQL Server 2005>configuration tools>Sql Server Surface Area Configuration>Surface Area Configuration for service and connections` and allow remote connection.
   - I located listenALL at `Microsoft SQL Server 2005>configuration tools>Sql Server Surface Area Configuration>Sql Server configuration manager>protocol for instancename>TCPIP>protocol` which was yes
   - I Located IPALL at `Microsoft SQL Server 2005>configuration tools>Sql Server Surface Area Configuration>Sql Server configuration manager>protocol for instancename>TCPIP>IP addresses` and as in the second link i posted ,i removed `0` from TCP Dynamic Ports and assigne `90000` to TCP Port
   - I try to restart the database engine it keeps on saying: `the request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. even though i undo every thing but still.Doesn't start from service manager.And it affected the SQLEXPress that got installed after i installed Visual Studio
   - i uninstalled the named instance but the SQLExpress is having the same behavior

Anyone to help me?this is critical thanks for reading this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find free port with help of [TCPview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) and then assign your DB Server to it.

Comment: ok! thanks for your reply.I thought something was wrong with my process of assigning a new port number.Is the service not starting because of port conflict?

Comment: I think it is most probable reason.